# Como redimensiona um JPanel dentro de um JScrollPane automaticamente?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Apos adicionar uma quantidade botoes maior do que o `JPanel` suporta, eu gostaria de atualizar(aumentar o `JPanel`) automaticamente, como eu posso fazer isso?

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private static int tamanho = 429;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    teste frame = new teste();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static int qtButton = 0 ;

public teste() 
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 900, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
    scroll.setBounds(10, 11, 464, 439);
    contentPane.add(scroll);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    scroll.setViewportView(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(390, 1000));

    JButton adicionar = new JButton("Adicionar");
    adicionar.setBounds(481, 11, 134, 23);
    contentPane.add(adicionar);

    adicionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            gerarButton(panel);

        }
    });
}
public static void gerarButton(JPanel panel)
{
    JButton NewButton = new JButton("New button");
    NewButton.setBounds(10, 11 + (34 * qtButton), 425, 23);
    panel.add(NewButton);

    qtButton ++;

    tamanho = 11 + (34 * qtButton) + 50;

    if(qtButton == 16)
    {
    }

    panel.repaint();
}
```

Como podem ver na imagem abaixo, o ultimo botão fica fora do panel, e eu gostaria de que quando isso acontecesse, eu conseguisse redimensionar o `panel` para que ele aumente de tamanho, assim cabendo o ultimo botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: De novo? Ficar criando duplicata não vai fazer sua pergunta ser respondida mais rápido. Tenha paciencia. Se ninguem respondeu, ou é porque sua pergunta não está clara, ou porque ninguem que entenda do assunto viu a pergunta ainda.

Comment: @DiegoF Não é a mesma pergunta, leia novamente. peço que crie um projeto e teste o código antes de me acusar de duplicata.

Comment: É a mesma duvida. E você ainda pede que alguem faça por você, o que é pior. E o código não tem problema, eu testei aqui e o botão é adicionado e o scroll funciona normalmente.

Comment: Na outra pergunta pedi ajuda para FAZER o Scroll e nessa pergunta pedi ajuda para alterar o tamanho do JPanel caso os JButtons excedam o tamanho do mesmo.
Eu não sabia que nesse fórum era errado pedir um exemplo para meu melhor entendimento, já que criei o código acima apenas para diminuir o tamanho da pergunta, ao invés de colocar o código que realmente estou usando, me desculpe.

Comment: Quando você adiciona uma quantidade de botões muito grande, o ultimo botão sai para fora do JPanel e eu gostaria de alterar o tamanho do JPanel para que caiba todos os botoes em vez de ficar aquele espaço em branco quando se desce o scroll.

Comment: *Obs: peço que deem um exemplo usando o código acima.*  - do jeito que você escreveu, deu a entender que você quer que alguem faça por você, não que seja proibido, mas pedir que façam por você não é bem visto.  E eu testei o código do jeito que você adicionou, não deu esse problema de "espaço em branco".Talvez o problema seja a renderização da sua IDE.

Comment: Vou colocar uma imagem explicando exatamente o meu problema.

Comment: Ainda não vi o problema, aquele espaçamento é o mesmo que está entre os botões.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40444/discussion-between-lucas-carezia-and-diego-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algumas mudanças no seu código, todas as alterações estão comentadas.
Em resumo, para fazer os botões se disporem automaticamente no `JPanel`, foi necessário configurar um [**Layout Manager**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), escolhi o [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) por atender o alinhamento vertical do botões, como você informou na pergunta:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Teste extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static int tamanho = 429;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Teste frame = new Teste();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static int qtButton = 0;

    public Teste() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 900, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        //aqui eu isolo a localização do scrollpane
        scroll.setLocation(10, 11);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
        //alterei pra final para que fosse possivel
        //chamar o componente dentro da classe anonima
        //do actionPerformed
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        //aqui defino um boxlayout, e a forma de alinhamento
        //dos componentes, no caso, somente em vertical
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(464, 439));
        //adicionar borda transparente ao painel
        //defini right e left pros botoes não ficarem
        //colados na borda
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 0, 5));
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);
        //vincula o tamanho do panel pro tamanho do scroll
        scroll.setSize(panel.getSize());

        JButton adicionar = new JButton("Adicionar");
        adicionar.setBounds(481, 11, 134, 23);
        contentPane.add(adicionar);

        adicionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gerarButton(panel);

            }
        });
    }

    public static void gerarButton(JPanel panel) {
        JButton NewButton = new JButton("New button");
        //pro botão ficar com tamanho maximo no BoxLayout
        // é preciso definir a dimensão maxima do botao
        //Integer.MAX_VALUE definir a maior largura possivel
        NewButton.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, NewButton.getMinimumSize().height));
        //adicionei um espaçamento pro proximo botao não
        //ficar colado, você pode alterar a vontade
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        panel.add(NewButton);

        qtButton++;
        tamanho = 11 + (34 * qtButton) + 50;

        if (qtButton == 16) {
        }
        //o revalidate deve ser aplicado ao componente root
        //neste caso, o JFrame
        //pra evitar problemas com tamanho de outros containers
        //da tela
        panel.getRootPane().revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Olà, e caso eu queira adicionar uma borda, para os botoês não ficarem colados com eles mesmo e nem com o JPanel, qual método eu usaria ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia só adicionar uma `EmptyBorder` no painel dos botoes, setando o espaçamento a direita e a esquerda. Atualizei o código